# A basic gridster example request

Tags: gridster

I can create the gridster dashboard but I do not understand how to get/manage data inside each gridster widget.

As an example:
Say I have a widget that I want to capture memory consumption, cpu utilization and disk space available. In my mind that is three labels that have data attributes assigned to them.

1. How do I get the labels in the gridster widget?
2. How do I bind the values/update the values/

I believe that an html file needs to be associated with each widget. I can’t figure out how to do it or if that is actually right. In my `layout.html.erb` I am using the following for my layout:

```
<div class="gridster"> 
   <ul> 
     <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data- sizey="1"></li>
     <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
 ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, a gridster "widget" is an arbitrary element that is either:

- chosen upon initializing gridster by the the [widget_selector](http://gridster.net/#widget_class_opt)
  option, which can be a CSS Selector string or a jQuery collection of HTMLElements, it defaults to `li`, which is why you don't need it if your grid is based on an an `<ul>`:

```js
var MyGrid = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_selector: 'li',
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
}).data('gridster');
```

- provided after initialization to gridster by the [add_widget](http://gridster.net/#add_widget_method) method, which returns a jQuery wrapper for the created widget:

  `var newWidget = MyGrid.add_widget = $("<li class='new'>My New Widget</li>");`

So you could create your dashboard items, select them, and pass them upon gridster initialization, or you can add them one by one with your data each time. You also don't have to use ul/li, I've used this with divs and it works fine as long as you initialize gridster on the parent container and pass it a jQuery collection of the 'widget' elements.

```js
<ul>
    <li id='first' class='dash-widgets'></li>
    <li id='second' class='dash-widgets'></li>
</ul>

$('#first').data({name:'cpu',speed:'1'});
var widgets = $('.dash-widgets');

var MyGrid = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_selector: widgets,
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
}).data('gridster');

var newWidget = MyGrid.add_widget = $("<li id='new'>My New Widget</li>");
newWidget.data({name:'mem',speed:'-1'});
```

Comment: What do you mean by collection of widgets? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Vnge `var widgets= $('.dash-widgets')` returns a jQuery collection of all the DOM elements of the class dash-widgets. You pass this variable to the `widget_selector` attribute. Assuming your dash-widget elements have the appropriate data-row/col/sizex/sizey attributes, it should work. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/
I haven't tried it, but I think the reason for passing a collection instead of just a class name is to put multiple things in, i.e. `$('.widgets, li, div.specialWidget')` Not sure why you would want to do that, but I think that's why.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Would you be able to check out my gridster question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571150/gridster-not-dynamically-moving-widgets