# Gridster not dynamically moving widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, gridster

I am trying to use [Gridster.js](http://www.gridster.net) to do some drag and drop functionality in my project.

I am using a bunch of divs for my widgets, with forms and buttons inside of these, instead of using an unordered list.

My issue is that my first column is not being able to drag, and i can not drop my widgets anywhere. They just drop to back to their original spot

Here is my layout:

```
<div class="gridster">
     <div class="dragMe" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
                <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
     </div>
     <div class="dragMe" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
                <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
     </div>
     <div class="dragMe" data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
                <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
     </div>
     <div class="dragMe" data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
                <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
     </div>

... ETC
</div>
```

and here is my js, which is in doc ready

```
var gridster = $('.gridster').gridster({
            widget_margins: [5,5],
            widget_selector: '.dragMe',
            widget_base_dimensions: [264, 103],
            max_cols: 5,
            max_rows: 5,
            resize: {
                enable: true
            },
            draggable: {
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    dragged = 1;
                },
                stop: function(event, ui){
                    var id = this.$helper[0].attributes[0].value;
                    var row = this.$helper[0].attributes[1].value;
                    var col = this.$helper[0].attributes[2].value;
                    console.log(id, row, col);
                }, 
                items: '.dragMe',
                limit: true
            }
        }).data('gridster');
```

I have both grister.js and the css file. Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something else in your code that is messing it up; check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed6ED/), I copied and pasted your code and only added:

```
.dragMe {
    background-color:#0f0;
}
.preview-holder {
    background-color:#000!important;
}
```

Just coloring them so you can see the widgets. Other than that, the only thing I changed was the text of the buttons and your "...ETC". It doesn't drag if you try and drag it by the button, but you can drag from anywhere else on the widget.

If for some reason you need to drag by the button, I would recommend changing it to a non input/button element and simulating whatever functionality you need with JavaScript.

When my grid gives me trouble, here's what I check:

- Opening/Closing tags all match
- data attributes make sense (Gridster gets crazy if widgets overlap)
- Styles are being applied appropriately - make certain it is
  *supposed* to look like what you think.

  I had a couple times where I was expecting to see one thing, and because I didn't assumed the javascript was at fault, but it was missing CSS styles.

Comment: would you possibly know why I am unable to move some widgets? I dont need to move the button, I am fine moving its container. 
The grid that I am working with is a 5x5, I now switched to it an unordered list because i was not able to get anywhere. 

My first column and my last widget don't see to want to move by trying to drag them, but they will move when others are dragged to their position

Comment: @Vnge Without seeing more code, and based on that description, this sounds very familiar. The are acting strange and you can't explain it... you try different forks, you read about people who have done it, you copy and paste an entire working example from jsfiddle into your project and it's still not working... for me it was a combination of the reasons I listed in my answer. If you can you provide a fiddle with a demonstration of the problem or a link, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Vnge Did this solve your issue? If so, would you mind marking it solved? I did come over here per your request from the other question :-) If it's still not working I would be happy to take a look at a more specific issue. I am able to get it working in a 5x5 grid using divs, per your initial code samples. I have added more blocks and updated the fiddle as such: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed6ED/3/

Comment: one issue why some of my items weren't moving was because there wasn't a clearfix inside of some of the buttons. I am not actually sure why that was the solution. but this definitely helped out! Ill mark it as resolved

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help! My problems seem to normally be from styles. It helps me when I get really out of whack to remove all my CSS and verify that its working with just the demo CSS from their site, and then gradually update the CSS to mine. (And of course making sure that the data attributes make sense)

Answer (score 1):

I thing Gridster requires one element (such as `div` or `ul`) below the `<div class="gridster">` element:

```
<div class="gridster">
     <div class="gridster-container">
         <div class="dragMe" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
            <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
         </div>
         <div class="dragMe" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
            <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
         </div>
         <div class="dragMe" data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
            <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
         </div>
         <div class="dragMe" data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <form>
            <button>//button stuff here </button>
          </form>
         </div>

    ... ETC
     </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var gridster = $(".gridster div.gridster-container").gridster({...
```

You can also use `ul` and `li` like they are using in their website.

Answer (score -1):

I tested it for a very long time, you have to erase this from your code:

`widget_base_dimensions: [264, 103]`

and your widgets get organized.